# Nested anonymous functions in Clojure

Tags: function, clojure

Are nested anonymous function legal or not? I wrote the following for the [problem #107](https://www.4clojure.com/problem/107) of 4clojure:

```
(fn [n] #(reduce * (repeat n %)))
```

which passed all the 3 tests, however when i try it with the test 3 in repl i get an IllegalStateException saying that nested #()s are not allowed:

```
IllegalStateException Nested #()s are not allowed  
clojure.lang.LispReader$FnReader.invoke (LispReader.java:628)

CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: n 
in this context, compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:1:44) 

RuntimeException Unmatched delimiter: )  

clojure.lang.Util.runtimeException (Util.java:221)

RuntimeException Unmatched delimiter: )  

clojure.lang.Util.runtimeException (Util.java:221)

CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: % 
in this context, compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:0:0) 

RuntimeException Unmatched delimiter: )  

clojure.lang.Util.runtimeException (Util.java:221)

RuntimeException Unmatched delimiter: )  

clojure.lang.Util.runtimeException (Util.java:221)

RuntimeException Unmatched delimiter: )  

clojure.lang.Util.runtimeException (Util.java:221)

RuntimeException Unmatched delimiter: )  

clojure.lang.Util.runtimeException (Util.java:221)
```

Why this cant be passed on repl but on 4clojure?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Nested anonymous functions are perfectly OK. But you can't nest the #() reader macro, because then it's not well defined - we can't know if by `%1` the programmer meant the first argument to the outer function literal or the first argument to the inner function literal.

You'll need to type the inner function out 'longhand' (using `fn`) if you want to evaluate the entire test form.

```
(fn [n]
  (fn [m] 
    (reduce * (repeat n m))))
```

It working on 4Clojure must likely be because they evaluate the form you provide before inserting it into the test forms. As such, the #() macro has already been expanded (to a `fn*`) when the test form is evaluated.

Comment: i was wondering, because my version with the `#()` reader macro also passed the test on 4clojure, but not in my repl. Thanks anyway for your explanation

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood your question a bit then. In that case the #() must already have been macro-expanded when it's inserted into the test forms

Comment: DOC; in case anyone looks for it: Ctrl-F for: `#() forms cannot be nested` in [clj-doc](http://clojure.org/reader)

Comment: `because they evaluate the form you provide` - actually we just *read* the form you provide first. The `#()` syntax is expanded by the reader, not by evaluation, so this is sufficient. Good point, though - I never noticed that this means there are solutions valid in 4clojure that don't work locally.